# Reading an XML File, storing its contents

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, portlet

I'm working on a portlet right now. I am basically a little stuck on one portion where I have to read an XML file which will have a bunch of items in the same format:

```
 <item> 
    <title>Some title</title>
    <event_date>Some date</event_date>
    <event_start_time>Some start time</event_start_time>
    <event_location>Some location</event_location>
 </item>
```

I was wondering what the best way to do this was. I just need to get each of these items and store them in a list so that I can display them nicely later.

Does anyone have any recommendations?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have a look at JAXP (DOM), DOM4J or JDOM parsing API.

Comment: Use JAXB; then you won't have to write any tedious parsing code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create the item object and add jaxb annotation then you will be able to marshall(write),unmarshall(read) the xml file.
https://jaxb.java.net/tutorial/